# Can not query posts by category in WordPress loop

Tags: php, wordpress

As the title says, when I try and query my posts to show what posts belongs to which category it just displays all the posts, to see if I was making a mistake in the code or loop I tried to search fort tags instead and this worked

```
<section class="background-wrapper">
<section class="content">
<div class="heading"><h1>Posts tagged with "coding"..</h1></div>
<div class="module-wrapper">

<?php if (have_posts()): ?>
<?php query_posts('cat=design');//NOTE USING ('tag=css') WORKED ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php wpb_set_post_views(get_the_ID()); //storing a value of a page view ?>

  <div class="module">
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <!-- Post Title -->
    <h1 class="post-title">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </h1>
    <!-- /Post Title -->

    <?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index'); // Build your custom callback length in functions.php ?>
```

Does the code need to be different when querying for tags?

Comment: I don't think you can use `cat=design`. Instead you'd probably want to use `query_posts( 'category_name=design' );`. Using `cat`, it expects the param to be the ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the query you're using `query_posts('cat=###')` then you need to give the query the **category Id** not the name.
If you don't know the Id offhand, you can find it before you do the query with something close to this:

```
$categories = get_the_category(); //gets all the categories
$i=1; 
$name='design'; 
$id='';
while(count($categories) > i){   //Loops through the categories
    if(($categories[$i-1]->cat_name)==$name){ 
        $id=$categories[$i-1]->cat_ID;  //Sets the variable $id to be the id you need
    }
    i++; 
};
```

`$id` should be the category Id you need to do the query you were using.

Answer (score 0):

Query posts is almost always a bad idea but that is beyond the scope of your question. However, if I understand your question right I stumbled across the possible answer yesterday in regards to querying categories and tags when building up your arguments:

```
//category and tag intersection
'category__and' => 'category', 'tag__in' => 'post_tag',
```

Here is my default template for querying with WP_Query in case you'd like to swap yours out with it.

```
$args  = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => -1, //-1 shows all
    //'offset'          => 0,
    'category'        => 'design',
    'orderby'         => 'post_date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    //'include'         => ,
    //'exclude'         => ,
    //'meta_key'        => ,
    //'meta_value'      => ,
    'post_type'       => 'post',
    //'post_mime_type'  => ,
    //'post_parent'     => ,
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query -> have_posts()) {
    while ( $query -> have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();  {
    //do stuff with the query data returned here
    }
}
```